# Как по клику по строке dbGrid получить значение из ячейки столбца?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

Необходимо при клике на любом месте строки в компоненте dbGrid получить значение из ячейки столбца id. Как я понимаю отслеживать это дело нужно с помощью события oncellclick, но я не знаю как дальше получить значение из заветной ячейки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
var 
  s: string;
begin
  s := Column.Field.AsString;
end;
```

Comment: нет свойства column, есть columns, но Field уже нет в списке

Comment: @КонстантинСтрамаус Какое "свойство"? `Column` - это параметр обработчика события.

Comment: Спасибо, так с данным способом разобрался, но он выдаёт только значение из ячейки по которой кликнули, а можно сделать так чтобы выделялась при клике строка полностью, и выводилось значение только из 1 столбца?

Comment: `s := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('id').AsString;`

Comment: Оно работает только для первой записи, для остальных выдаёт ошибку SIGSEGV

Comment: Нет, оно работает для всех записей. Создайте простейший проект с одной формой и таблицей, чтобы в этом убедиться.

Comment: Ошибка оказалась в том что не нужно подключать datasorse в sqlquery

Comment: Я протестировал этот код с `TClientDataSet`-ом, загруженным из XML-файла. А Вы?

Comment: Всё, ошибка из за datasourse, потому что он был подключен в свойствах sqlquery. спасибо за помощь, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Обращайтесь непосредственно к Dataset, который получает значения из БД/
к примеру:

```
Edit.Text := DataSet.FieldByName('UNICUM_NUM').AsString;
```